# Read userPassword field from ldap server in clear text

Tags: oracle, migration, ldap, oid, opendj

I am building a utility that will copy users and groups from an Oracle Internet Directory server and transfer them into an OpenDJ LDAP server.

After a lot of work i have come to the point where i read User's attributes from OID and i am stuck in the userPassword field.

Is there any way that i can read the password in clear text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only read the password in clear text if it was put there in clear text. Mostly it isn't, for very good security *and legal* reasons. However you don't need to for this purpose: just copy the contents exactly as they are. That will include a tag showing whatever hashing scheme was used on the password, and the target LDAP server should handle that correctly.

Comment: ok, i have managed it to work. Thanks. But could userPassword be retrieved as plain text?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy The first sentence of my reply answers that question.